# How to efficiently map data between time series in python

Tags: python, numpy, testing, time-series, resampling

I'm trying to create an efficient function for re-sampling time-series data.

**Assumption:** Both sets of time-series data have the same start and end time. (I do this in a separate step.)

## Resample function (inefficient)

```py
import numpy as np

def resample(desired_time_sequence, data_sequence):
    downsampling_indices = np.linspace(0, len(data_sequence)-1, len(desired_time_sequence)).round().astype(int)
    downsampled_array = [data_sequence[ind] for ind in downsampling_indices] 
    return  downsampled_array
```

### Speed testing

```py
import timeit
def test_speed(): resample([1,2,3], [.5,1,1.5,2,2.5,3,3.5,4,4.5,5,5.5,6])
print(timeit.timeit(test_speed, number=100000))
# 1.5003695999998854
```

Interested to hear any suggestions.

Comment: Please include a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in your question.

Comment: @jfaccioni Do you have any recommendations on how I could get more minimal and reproducible than this?

Comment: I think this might do better on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Thanks @gmds I'll try it on code review and delete here soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replacing

```
downsampled_array = [data_sequence[ind] for ind in downsampling_indices]
```

with

```
downsampled_array = data_sequence[downsampling_indices]
```

provided 7x speedup on my testing data.

Code used to measure the speedup:

```
import timeit

f1 = """
def resample(output_len, data_sequence):
    downsampling_indices = np.linspace(0, len(data_sequence)-1, output_len).round().astype(int)
    downsampled_array = [data_sequence[ind] for ind in downsampling_indices]
    return downsampled_array

resample(output_len, data_sequence)
"""

f2 = """
def resample_fast(output_len, data_sequence):
    downsampling_indices = np.linspace(0, len(data_sequence)-1, output_len).round().astype(int)
    downsampled_array = data_sequence[downsampling_indices]
    return downsampled_array

resample_fast(output_len, data_sequence)
"""


setup="""
import numpy as np
data_sequence = np.random.randn(10000)
output_len = 752
"""

print(timeit.timeit(f1, setup, number=1000))
print(timeit.timeit(f2, setup, number=1000))

# prints:
# 0.30194038699846715
# 0.041797632933594286
```